# Ignoring a property of collection member AutoMapper C#

Tags: c#, mapping, automapper

I have next enteties

```
public class TagDTO
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
   public List<ImageDTO> Images { get; set; }
}

public class ImageDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<TagDTO> Tags { get; set; } 
}
```

And when I'm mapping from `Image` to `ImageDTO` i do not need `List<Images>` in `TagDTO` class. But in other cases this property is necessary. Can I configure in AutoMapper to Ignore `List<ImagesDTO> Images`, like this

```
 CreateMap<Image, ImageDTO>().ForMember(x => x.Tags.Select(p=>p.Images),
 opts => opts.Ignore());
```